# How to Print HTML file using receipt printer

Tags: c#, html, printing

I have a sale invoice as a HTML file. I need write program to print that invoice using Epson TM-T82II receipt printer in C#. i am new to program.. therefore i need to know what is the best way to do that and how can i do it?

here i attached the picture of HTML file and HTML code.
[please click to see HTML Invoice screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6RiM.jpg)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style>
body {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 0 50pt 0 50pt;
}
table td, table th, table.sales th, table td.footer-text {
    font-size: 8pt;
}
h1 {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    color:chocolate;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
h2 {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    color:chocolate;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
h3 {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
table.sales td {
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
}
table.sales th {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
tr.saleline td {
    border-bottom-color:chocolate;
    border-bottom-width: 1pt;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.signature {
    display: none;
}
.horizontal-line {
    border: 0;
    height: 4pt;
    color:chocolate;
    background-color: chocolate;
}
.total {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.1em;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.block1 {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom
}
.block2 {
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom
}
.block3 {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.block4 {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.block5 {
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.block6 {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.block7 {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.block8 {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.block9 {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.block10 {
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.block11 {
    text-align:left;
    padding: 25px 0 15px 0;
}
.extracols {
    border-style:solid; 
    border-color:gray;
}
table.extracols {
    border-top-width: 1pt;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 1pt;
    border-left-width: 1pt;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin: 0 0 15pt 0;
}
table.extracols th {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 1pt;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-color:gray;
    border-style:solid; 
    background-color:#CCC;
}
table.extracols td {
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 1pt;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-color:gray;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#footer {
    margin-top: 35px;
}
.footer-text {
    font-size: inherit;
    font-size: 0.97em   
}
</style>
</head>
<body  style="padding: 20 20 20 20">
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom:20px"><table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:left;"></td>
          <td class="block2" align="right"><h3>Y.P.Brothers</h3>
           No:55/B,<br/>Samagipura,<br/>Sewanagala.
<br/>077-6977139
<br/>mecduino@gmail.com
<br/>
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><hr class="horizontal-line"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%"> 
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:10px 0 20px 0;"><table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td width="33%" class="block3"><strong>Bill To</strong><br />
                ANUSHA SURIYA<br/>
                </td>
                <td class="block4"><strong></strong><br />

                </td>
                <td class="block5" align="right"><h1>invoice #1</h1>
                  <b>Date</b>: Oct 9, 2015
<br/><b>Due Date</b>: Oct 9, 2015
                 </td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" class="sales">

              <!-- Headers -->
              <tr>
                 <th align="center">Qty</th>  <th align="center">Item</th>  <th align="right">Price</th>  <th align="right">Amount</th> 
              </tr>

              <!-- Rows -->
                <tr class="saleline">  <td align="left">12</td>   <td align="left">helaligth 35/=</td>   <td align="right">35.00</td>   <td align="right">420.00</td> </tr> 
  <tr class="saleline">  <td align="left">12</td>   <td align="left">200p CR SR 195/=</td>   <td align="right">195.00</td>   <td align="right">2,340.00</td> </tr> 
  <tr class="saleline">  <td align="left">36</td>   <td align="left">Sunlight 35g</td>   <td align="right">6.00</td>   <td align="right">216.00</td> </tr> 

              <!-- Totals -->
              <tr><td align="right" colspan="3">Subtotal</td><td align="right">2,976.00</td></tr><tr><td align="right" colspan="3"><b>TOTAL</b></td><td align="right"><b>2,976.00</b></td></tr><tr><td align="right" colspan="3">Less Payment</td><td align="right">2,760.00</td></tr><tr class="total"><td align="right" colspan="3"><strong>Balance Due</strong></td><td align="right">216.00</td></tr>

            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" style="margin-top:30px">
        <tr>
          <td width="50%" class="block6"><h2></h2>

          </td>
          <td width="50%" class="block7" align="right"><h2></h2>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table class="block11" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td><table></table></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  <div class="signature">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="left">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:30px"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Signed by:</b> 
<br/><b>Date:</b> 
<br/><b>Signature:</b><br/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

<div id="footer">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><span class="footer-text">Thank you for your business.</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what have you tried? seems like you're just asking someone to do your work for you ...

Comment: I am try to print above invoice using receipt printer.. i'm new to program. therefore if someone have an able to write this program for me as a help i really appreciate it.

Comment: I hate to be that person, but [read this please](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and we can go from there. (besides, the fact that you don't know and didn't try, doesn't mean somebody else needs to do it for you. somebody might, but odds are against it i'm afraid)